# How do I access the data in a join SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, syntax, sqlalchemy

Given the following sess query:

```
sess = DBSession()  
reg =  sess.query(Registration,Schedule).join(Schedule,Registration.classcode==Schedule.classcode).filter(Registration.registration_no==reg_id)
```

How the heck do I address the fields in the result 'reg'?

reg.timeofentry throws an error:  `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

I am rapidly learning to loath SQLAlchemy for all it's cryptic wrappers around perfectly simply SQL syntaxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oddly enough, the names within the named tuple `row` as returned from iterating the result `reg` in this case would be be `Registration` and `Schedule`:

```
for row in reg:
   print row.Registration, row.Schedule
```

I'm not able to reproduce your specific error message "can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly".  If I attempt to access a name on the KeyedTuple that doesn't exist, there's a clear message:

```
AttributeError: 'KeyedTuple' object has no attribute 'imfake'
```

The behavior of the return value of query should be less cryptic after reading [the intro to Querying in the ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying).